# UITableView not autosizing to fit its UIView superview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, autoresizingmask

I am trying to make the height of a `UITableView` smaller by changing the size of its parent, a `UIView`.

I cannot directly change the `UITableView` size, just the `UIView` due to the way my project is set up.

The `UIView` changes its size and origin, which moves the table down fine, but this means that the bottom of the table is cut off. I have to do this after the table has been drawn and using `layoutIfNeeded` makes the origin (0,0) again.

I have tried to change the `autoresizingmasks` on both the table and the `UIView`, but this didn't work. I tried to make the view 100x100 (to test) but the height was still its full size however it made scrolling the table only possible in the 100x100 `UIView` space.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

The code I am using is this: `contentView` is a subview of self.view and the table is a child of this.
`isTableView` is a `BOOL` which is passed to the object when init, which stops the layout being rendered again. without this, the view resets to its original size as I said before.
`yaxis` is just an extra spacing variable if needed, it just allows more space if needed

```
UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (ad != nil) {
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            [ad setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];
        }else{
            [ad setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
        }
        
        CGRect bannerViewFrame = ad.frame;
        CGRect contentViewFrame = contentView.frame;
        if (_bannerViewIsVisible) {
            bannerViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
            bannerViewFrame.origin.y = yaxis;
            
            contentViewFrame.size.height = viewController.view.frame.size.height - ([self getBannerHeight]+yaxis);
            contentViewFrame.origin.y = [self getBannerHeight]+yaxis;
            
        }else{
            bannerViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
            bannerViewFrame.origin.y = -[self getBannerHeight];
            
            contentViewFrame.origin.y = yaxis;
            contentViewFrame.size.height = viewController.view.frame.size.height-yaxis;
        }
        [UIView animateWithDuration:[UIView areAnimationsEnabled] ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
            contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
            if(!isTableView)
                [contentView layoutIfNeeded];
            ad.frame = bannerViewFrame;
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use anchors?

Comment: After resizing do you reload the tableview contents so that the new heights are used?

Comment: @PraveenS Yes, i tried this but it didn't help

Comment: @LlamaGoingNorth "In different way"-What does this mean?? Can you please specify the method you followed so that others could benefit from it. Thanks :)

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya I think I used a different approach but I cannot remember what exactly I did, sorry. Feel free to ask a question and send me the link if you're having similar problems

Answer (score 1):

i've solved such a problem by placing dynamic controls and table on separate view. I had different navigation bar height + iAd banner appearing and disappearing.

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
  if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
  {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, self.view.frame.size.height - 50);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;

  }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 0);

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yIf you add your UITableView to UIView dynamically, try to set autoresizingMask:

```
tableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
```

and then add tableView as subView:

```
[view addSubView:tableView];
```

hope this helps

Comment: I'm not making my table dynamically, I'm using a storyboard. I tried to do it programmatically but it didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the frame for UITableview before or after adding the parent UIView as like `[myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(parentView.frame.origin.x+5,parentView.frame.origin.y+5,parentView.frame.size.width-10,parentView.frame.size.height-10)];`?

Comment: I cant set the frame of the table, I want it to fit to the size of the superview (the UIView)